# Using jade in angularjs, on include loosing the scope

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angularjs-scope, pug, sails.js

I am using node with sails as my server. My problem is when I am trying to include a jade file using include I am not able to access the scope.
Please go through the below code

```
body(data-ng-controller="mainCtrl")
   include navigation
   div(data-ng-view="")
   block content
```

There view renders dynamically. I would like to access that controller even in the included template but it is not working...Please help me I am very new to this technology

Thanks in advance

Comment: "not working" = not very helpful = not likely to get you a good answer. And using two MVC frameworks is not recommended, especially for someone new to that technology.

Comment: I agree, sails.js and AngularJS will be a bit daunting for a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Is 'include navigation' referring to a Jade include or an AngularJS include?